# How do I take nRF24l01(slave) Register data using stm32f103 (master) through MISO pin

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, microcontroller, spi

I'm trying to make a custom library for nRF24l01 for a stm32f103 target device, and I am writing code for a primary TX device.
And here I'm trying to read the register contents of nRF by sending the R_REGISTER command along with the address I am looking for, but I'm not able to figure out how to read the data after the R_REGISTER command is transmitted.

And i'm using the standard stm32f10x.h header file which comes along with startup files on Kiel uVision5.

Here are the configurations,

**clock setup**

```
RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_HSION;    //HSI on
while( !(RCC_CR_HSIRDY & (RCC->CR)) );  //wait till its ready
//clocks for peripherals 
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN; //enable clock forport A
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_AFIOEN; //enable clock for alternate functions
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN; //enable clock for SPI1
```

**GPIO setup**
these are my custom-defined functions, they just work fine

```
//GPIO pin setup as alternate function
pin_mode(IOPA, GPIOA, 7, op_50MHz, op_afpp);    //MOSI pin as GPIO alternate_pin can run upto 50MHz
pin_mode(IOPA, GPIOA, 6, ip, ip_pupd);  //MISO pin as GPIO alternate_pin can run upto 50MHz
pin_mode(IOPA, GPIOA, 5, op_50MHz, op_afpp);    //SCK pin as GPIO alternate_pin can run upto 50MHz
pin_mode(IOPA, GPIOA, 4, op_50MHz, op_gppp);    //CS pin as GPIO general_puspose_pin can run upto 50MHz
```

**SPI setup**

```
SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_MSTR;  //master mode
SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_BR_0 | SPI_CR1_BR_1 | SPI_CR1_BR_2;    //at 571Kbps, max 31Mbps
SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SSI;   //Software slave management enabled
SPI1->CR2 |= SPI_CR2_SSOE;  //SS o/p enable
SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;   //turn on the SPI
```

**Im stuck here**

```
uint8_t SPI_read_uint8_t(uint8_t addr){
    uint8_t reg_val;
    //sending the read command first along with address where we are reading from
    delay_us(50);
    digital_writepin(GPIOA, 4, LOW);
    SPI1->DR = (R_REGISTER | addr);  //sending the R_REGISTER command along with address
    while( (SPI1->SR) & (SPI_SR_BSY) );

    //please help here, how do I read the Register data from MISO pin
```

[image: The SPI read operation should look like this]

Answer (score 1):

```
uint8_t spi_read_write(uint8_t data)
{
    while(SPI1 -> SR & SPI_SR_RXNE) (void)*(volatile uint8_t *)&SPI1 -> DR;   //clean the FIFO
    *(volatile uint8_t *)&SPI1 -> DR = data;
    while(!(SPI1 -> SR & SPI_SR_RXNE));
    return *(volatile uint8_t *)&SPI1 -> DR;
}

uint8_t youroperation(uint8_t command, uint16_t *data)
{
    uint8_t status;
    setCSLine();
    status = spi_read_write(command);
    *data = spi_read_write(0);
    *data |= ((uint16_t)spi_read_write(0)) << 8;
    clearCSLine();   
    return status
}
```

`youroperation` will return `Sn` status register
`command` parameter means `Cn` command bits
`data` will contain the Dx data bits

To read data from SPI slave you need to send dummy bytes because master provides the clock for the slave.